# Can't tell why I'm getting "TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly" error

Tags: python-3.x

I'm teaching myself to code so forgive me if the answer is obvious or my code is a wreck. I tried putting together a simple search engine that counts the number of times a word appears, but I keep getting the above error message so I can't even test it. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
def search(text_body, phrase):
    count = 0
    word_length = len(phrase)
    for i in text_body:
        if phrase == text_body[i:i+word_length]:
            count +=1 
    return count

text_body = "text text text text text"
phrase = input("Search for: ")
final_count = search(text_body, phrase)

print(final_count)
```

Edit: Apologies, the full error message is here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                             
  File "main.py", line 21, in <module>                                                                                                         
    final_count = search(text_body, phrase)                                                                                                    
  File "main.py", line 14, in search                                                                                                           
    if phrase == text_body[i:i+word_length]:                                                                                                   
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

Comment: Please always include the full error message.

Comment: Change `for i in text_body:` to `for i in range(len(text_body)):`

Comment: 1) The error message (aka "traceback" in Python) will tell you the line number throwing a fit. 2) In `text_body[i:i+word_length]`, what is the type of `i` and of `word_length`? This is something you can deduce by logging (`print(type(i))`) or by understanding the traceback.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already given a good explanation on why your code is breaking and a good fix, but to demonstrate this we can look at a simple `for` loop:

```
text_body = "text"
for i in text_body:
    print(i)
```

Which prints:

```
t
e
x
t
```

You can see from this that in the snippet:

```
text_body[i:i+word_length]
```

you're trying to do:

```
text_body['t':'t'+5]
```

Which is why Python is getting confused, since you're trying to add a string to an int, hence the error.

Something really important to note is that [Python strings actually have a method for exactly what you're doing already](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count):

```
>>> "text text text text text".count("text")
5
```

Or, for your case:

```
text_body.count(phrase)
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `i` in `for i in text_body:` is the next character from `text_body` (a one-character string). You cannot add a number and a string in `i+word_length`. You should iterate through the indexes:

```
for i in range(len(text_body)):
```

Better yet, use the function `text_body.index`.

Answer (score 0):

When python executes

```py
for i in text_body:
    if phrase == text_body[i:i + word_length]:
        count += 1
```

in the definition of `search` the value `i` picks up each element, instead of the index, and thus `i + word_length` throws the `TypeError`. Here is the solution, using `range()` instead of `for i in text_body`.

```py
for i in range(len(text_body)):
    if phrase == text_body[i:i + word_length):
        count += 1
```